# CodeIgniter unable to find a Class in production

Tags: php, codeigniter, yui-compressor

I'm using CodeIgniter and I've got YUI Compressor running, which works great locally. When I upload the site to my production server it says it can't find the YUI Compressor Class? I haven't changed anything, could this be an issue with my host not having something that I need to run the YUI Java?

Not sure what I can add to give examples since it's working locally, but not in my live site. The code is identical...very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the YUI compressor code stored? Are you deploying that along with everything else, or is it something you had to install?

If it's not something you're deploying, then maybe you need to either deploy it with everything else, or make sure it's installed in production.

If it is something you're deploying, then you need to verify that your development environment matches production, as far as PHP version, server version, and configuration.

Comment: I have the JAR's in a folder that I'm accessing via PHP Class. Locally the class is found without a problem. When I open the same path externally I get this error `Unable to load the requested class: yuicompressor`